# Deleting Specific Core Data Entity with Attribute Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

At the end of using a core data entity I need to delete it, but I only need to delete and entity with a specific value of attribute "name" how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You delete objects from Core Data by using the `deleteObject:` method on `NSManagedObjectContext`, and then saving changes.

If you already have the object that you want to delete, just do that. If you don't have it but know attribute values of the objects to delete, do a fetch request to get the objects, and delete the objects that are returned from the fetch.